# Exception handling for openssl decrypt In php

Tags: php, exception, encryption, error-handling

I need help for decryption algorithm in php.

I got error when I pass wrong encrypt data in my decryption function. so i need to handle error using exception. can it possible?

I tried to this code but no luck

```
function decrypt($encrypt_data) {
    $key = ENC_KEY;
    $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
    list($encrypted_data, $iv) = explode('::', base64_decode($encrypt_data), 2);

    try {
      if(openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, 'aes-256-cbc', $encryption_key, 0, $iv)) {
          throw new customException($encrypted_data);
      }
    }

    catch (customException $e) {
      echo $e->errorMessage();
    }

 }
```

But this function gives me error:-

> Warning: openssl_decrypt(): IV passed is only 7 bytes long, cipher
>   expects an IV of precisely 16 bytes, padding with \0 in abc.php

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning. Not the same thing. The function itself will pad the IV to be of the correct length and will still work. If you want to fix the warning, you could validate the IV before using it and pad it your self, if needed.

Comment: Btw, why are you throwing an exception if you the decryption works? You're also not actually saving the decrypted string.

Comment: @magnus thank's for comment. the decryption is not work when i pass wrong encrypt data. I need only error(warning) handling so i don't describe save or return data

Answer (score 1):

[As Magnus indicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187352/exception-handling-for-openssl-decrypt-in-php/50200684#comment87391493_50187352), the key and IV should be specific sizes for AES in CBC mode. The key size should be 32 bytes for AES-256 and the IV is identical to the block size: 16 bytes.

Generally any language will validate the size of the key and IV before using it, but PHP has had the nasty habit (for both the OpenSSL and mcrypt API's) of padding it with zero's if it is too small or cutting part of it when it is too large. This is probably because the underlying C-libraries do not validate the size either as the key and IV are passed as pointers rather than arrays or objects.

To fix this you should make sure that the key is exactly 32 randomized bytes (apparently it is because there is no warning) and that the IV consists of exactly 16 randomized bytes.

---

Note that it is a *security requirement* for CBC mode that the IV consists of 16 bytes that are fully unpredictable to an adversary. Just fixing the error by padding the IV with zeros yourself is therefore not recommended. Although the use of 7 bytes as IV is unlikely to directly lead to exploits you should *fix the protocol* rather than to rely on *workarounds in the code*.

As indicated, other cryptographic API's (for different languages) will strictly enforce to use keys and IV's of the correct size; if you keep using a 7 byte IV then all those runtimes may need workarounds as well.

Comment: Thank you Maarten Bodewes nice solution